# get the windows installation drive using python

Tags: python, window

How to detect the windows installation path or drive using python code ?

Comment: Are you using the win32 module for Python? http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['SYSTEMDRIVE']
'C:'
```

Comment: This will usually work, but that environment variable can easily be set to anything else.  At the very least, your program won't work in that case, and at worst, you have a security hole.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GetWindowsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) library to get the location of the Windows folder, and then you can use [`os.path.splitdrive`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) to get the drive letter.  For example:

```
import ctypes
import os

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
windows_directory = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
if kernel32.GetWindowsDirectoryW(windows_directory, 1024) == 0:
    # Handle error
else:
    windows_drive = os.path.splitdrive(windows_directory)[0]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `windows_drive = os.path.splitdrive(windows_directory.value)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WINDIR enviroment variable.

```
os.environ['WINDIR']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to just get the letter, and nothing else:

```
import os
os.environ['WINDIR'].split(":\\")[0]
```

Example output:

> >>> os.environ['WINDIR'].split(":\\")[0]
>
> 'C'